# What does "tap" mean in "as Trump taps advisors"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, idioms

`tap` was explained in the dictionary.
http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tap

In the article :Fannie, Freddie surge as Trump taps advisors who back privatization.
[Fannie, Freddie surge as Trump taps advisors who back privatization](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/fannie-freddie-surge-as-trump-taps-advisors-who-back-privatization-2016-11-10)

sentence 1.

> Fannie, Freddie surge as Trump taps advisors who back privatization.

The tap here means `to hit (someone or something) lightly especially with a small sound`?

senetence 2

> Ken Blackwell, who’s been tapped to lead the domestic transition team,

The tap here means `put into` or `selected` or `chosen`?

sentence 3

> John Paulson had been tapped to be a Trump advisor

The tap here means `selected` or `chosen`?

Comment: All three of these mean "to choose (someone) for a particular job", not "to hit something lightly".

Answer (score 3):

The term has been in use in this sense since the 1500s. [(See *tap (2)* here)](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=tap&allowed_in_frame=0)

> Extended sense "make use of" is first recorded 1570s.

The "make use of" has come to be used in the sense of *selected* or *chosen*.

It comes from "tapping" (putting a spigot on) a keg of ale or beer so that its contents can be drawn out.

Oddly enough, its original sense *was* from "tapping, or hitting something" because the spigot was driven into the bunghole of the keg using a mallet.

Comment: Physical spouts called "taps" are still hammered into maple trees to allow the sap to be collected, a process called "tapping."

Answer (score 1):

This idiom uses [definition 3](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tap):  "to choose (someone) for a particular job, honor, etc." [often with "for" or "to be"]

When I hear this idiom, I imagine a coach literally "tapping a player on the shoulder" to tell him that he should play in a game.

Comment: I always think "Tag, you're it!" like the children's game.